# How Makefiles Are Remade - don't understand official documentation

Tags: makefile, gnu

I can't understand chapter 3 of official gmake documentation starting from section 3.5

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles

Docs say:
... after reading in all makefiles make will consider each as a goal target and attempt to update it. If a makefile has a rule which says how to update it ...., it will be updated if necessary. After all makefiles have been checked, if any have actually been changed, make starts with a clean slate and reads all the makefiles over again. (It will also attempt to update each of them over again, but normally this will not change them again, since they are already up to date.) Each restart will cause the special variable MAKE_RESTARTS to be updated.

So I try with this mkfile ( presence of the -include as G.M. has suggested changes nothing ):

```
all:
        echo all $(MAKE_RESTARTS) aaa

#-include: mkfile

mkfile:
        echo touch
        touch mkfile
```

I expect that after mkfile runs first time mkfile modification time changed and make must run it again and again.
But nothing happens:

```
$ make -f  mkfile 
echo all  aaa
all aaa
$
```

Moreover, target "mkfile" not called as expecting from docs: after reading in all makefiles make will consider each as a goal target and attempt to update it.

What I'm misunderstand ? Can you, please, give an example of what docs mean about "remading" makefiles?

**UPD: I've tried Andreas' suggestions but got strange results again :**

1. original mkfile but run with --always-make

```
 $ make --always-make -f mkfile 
echo touch
touch
touch mkfile
echo all 1 aaa
all 1 aaa
```

here target "mkfile" runs once and target "all" runs once too. The results of consequence runs are repeatable.

2. If I change target "mkfile" to force run, results a strange and differ from invocation to invocation:
   mkfile:

```
all:
    echo all $(MAKE_RESTARTS) aaa

mkfile: force
    echo touch
    touch mkfile

force: ;
```

results:

```
$ make -f mkfile 
echo touch
touch
touch mkfile
echo touch
touch
touch mkfile
echo touch
touch
touch mkfile
................
touch mkfile
echo touch
touch
touch mkfile
echo all 16 aaa
all 16 aaa
$ make -f mkfile 
echo touch
touch
touch mkfile
echo touch
touch
touch mkfile
echo touch
touch
touch mkfile
echo all 2 aaa
all 2 aaa

$ make -f mkfile
echo touch
touch
touch mkfile
...............
touch mkfile
echo all 13 aaa
all 13 aaa
$
```

**UPD2 - about MAKE_RESTARTS**

`--always-make` respects MAKE_RESTARTS only if makefile's target has no prerequisites.

mkfile:

```
all:
    echo all $(MAKE_RESTARTS) aaa

mkfile:
    echo touch $(MAKE_RESTARTS)
    sleep 0.5
    touch mkfile
```

result:

```
$ make --always-make -f  mkfile
echo touch 
touch
sleep 0.5
touch mkfile
echo all 1 aaa
all 1 aaa
$
```

if makefile's target has force prerequisite, loop is infinite (I even try to set MAKE_RESTARTS by force to value greater than 0 )

mkfile:

```
MAKE_RESTARTS := 1

all:
    echo all $(MAKE_RESTARTS) aaa

mkfile: force
    echo touch $(MAKE_RESTARTS)
    sleep 0.5
    touch mkfile

force: ;
```

result:

```
$ make --always-make -f  mkfile
echo touch 1
touch 1
sleep 0.5
touch mkfile
echo touch 1
touch 1
sleep 0.5
touch mkfile
echo touch 1
touch 1
sleep 0.5
touch mkfile
^C
```

Comment: Don't know about MAKE_RESTARTS, but mkfile will be made if a) missing, or b) any of its prerequisites have a more recent timestamp. Since mkfile has no prerequisites its recipe will only be executed if mkfile missing (or make is invoked with --always-make/-B).

Comment: Note that in the example shown there is nothing to suggest that `mkfile` is actually a `makefile` so `make` will simply treat it as a normal target.  Try adding the line `-include mkfile` to the `makefile` shown.

Comment: `#-include: mkfile` --> `-include mkfile` -- please use the code I provided as-is.

Comment: He doesn't need to `include mkfile`.  He's running make with `-f mkfile` so `mkfile` is considered a makefile.

Comment: @MadScientist, yes -include useless here, so I commented it out (and say that in description).

Answer (score 2):

For this:

```
all:
        echo all $(MAKE_RESTARTS) aaa
mkfile:
        echo touch
        touch mkfile
```

When `make -f mkfile` runs it tries to build `mkfile`.  The make manual says that if a target has no prerequisites, then if it exists it's considered up-to-date (how can it be out of date when it doesn't depend on anything?)  Since the `mkfile` file exists (obviously), this rule is really a no-op.  If you want to see the behavior of rebuilding makefiles then the makefile has to have some prerequisite which shows that it's out of date.

If you run it with `--always-make` you'll run across [this statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) in the GNU make manual:

> GNU `make` proceeds to
> consider targets and their prerequisites using the normal algorithms;
> however, all targets so considered are always remade regardless of the
> status of their prerequisites.  **To avoid infinite recursion, if
> `MAKE_RESTARTS` is set to a number greater than 0 this option is
> disabled when considering whether to remake makefiles.**

(Emphasis added).

If you run with a `force` target, then it will be updated as you've seen.  For some operating systems this will run forever.  However for others, at some point the `touch` command will run fast enough that it won't actually change the modification time of the `mkfile` file; it will be so fast that the modification time before and after the command runs will be the same.  When a recipe runs but doesn't change the modification time of that target, then the target is not considered to be modified and any rules that depend on it will not be considered out-of-date because of that target.

When that happens, `make` believes that the target was not changed and it no longer re-execs itself.

Comment: If you want to have an infinite loop in your third example, add a `sleep 1` into your recipe before the `touch mkfile` to ensure that the modification time of `mkfile` is always newer than it was before.

Comment: thank you, it became more clear for me (except `--always-make` and `MAKE_RESTARTS` with force prerequisite. I wrote UPD2 section in original question).

Comment: But I think that your assumption - `touch` command will run fast enough. Isn't the all truth.  Initially I ran this example on ZFS filesystem on my weak notebook, and ZFS not update modification time always  instantly.  But when I try to run this example on much more powerful server with ext4 filesystem - infinite loop never breaks.

Comment: It's not related to the power of the system so much as the capabilities of the filesystem and the implementation of touch.  Some filesystems store timestamps at much higher granularity than others.  The coarser the granularity the more likely it is that you'll get an infinite loop.  Also some implementations of touch cannot set timestamps at fine-grained granularity (less than 1 second).

Comment: Regarding `--always-make` there are two things: first, it's not possible for `MAKE_RESTARTS` to be changed in a meaningful way by the makefile.  The documentation makes it clear that this variable cannot be changed.  Even if you set it in the makefile, that will not change make's internal understanding of the restart value which is set when make first starts up.  So this has no effect.

Comment: Second, the quoted text above describes that the `--always-make` flag itself is ignored when the restarted value is >0, but that doesn't mean that the included makefile won't be rebuilt for other reasons, if it's out of date.